# MyMediaLite Java Recommend method

Tags: java, c#, recommendation-engine

I found that in MyMediaLiteJava ([jcnewell/MyMediaLiteJava](https://github.com/jcnewell/MyMediaLiteJava/)
 on gitHub) is no Recommend method as it is in C# version of this recommender.
For example, in C# MyMediaLite docs Random recommender is method `Recommend (int user_id, int n=-1, ICollection< int > ignore_items=null, ICollection< int > candidate_items=null)` , but in Java version there's no such method..  Or maybe I'm missing something? 
 I just want to try to get at least random items for recommend.. 
 I also tried to re-write recommend method from C# to JAVA, but for me it's a little bit too hard, because I don't know some of C# analogs to Java. I'll leave here Recommend method code on C#, maybe I'd get some suggestions.

```
public virtual System.Collections.Generic.IList<Tuple<int, float>> Recommend(
        int user_id, int n = -1,
        System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<int> ignore_items = null,
        System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<int> candidate_items = null)
    {
        if (candidate_items == null)
            candidate_items = Enumerable.Range(0, MaxItemID - 1).ToList();
        if (ignore_items == null)
            ignore_items = new int[0];

        System.Collections.Generic.IList<Tuple<int, float>> ordered_items;

        if (n == -1)
        {
            var scored_items = new List<Tuple<int, float>>();
            foreach (int item_id in candidate_items)
                if (!ignore_items.Contains(item_id))
                {
                    float score = Predict(user_id, item_id);
                    if (score > float.MinValue)
                        scored_items.Add(Tuple.Create(item_id, score));
                }
            ordered_items = scored_items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            var comparer = new DelegateComparer<Tuple<int, float>>( (a, b) => a.Item2.CompareTo(b.Item2) );
            var heap = new IntervalHeap<Tuple<int, float>>(n, comparer);
            float min_relevant_score = float.MinValue;

            foreach (int item_id in candidate_items)
                if (!ignore_items.Contains(item_id))
                {
                    float score = Predict(user_id, item_id);
                    if (score > min_relevant_score)
                    {
                        heap.Add(Tuple.Create(item_id, score));
                        if (heap.Count > n)
                        {
                            heap.DeleteMin();
                            min_relevant_score = heap.FindMin().Item2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            ordered_items = new Tuple<int, float>[heap.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < ordered_items.Count; i++)
                ordered_items[i] = heap.DeleteMax();
        }

        return ordered_items;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to contact the authors about this?

Comment: No, haven't tried. Should I try?

Comment: Well, if anybody knows, why they leave out that method in the Java version, then it's the guys who decided to do so, right?